# How do I help my 5 year old sister with PTSD and serious behavioral issues?

Tags: toddler, pre-schooler, anger

Okay so I'm not a parent I'm a big sister. We're 14 years apart, different dads, single mom, etc. Sadly, her father was abusive and around long enough for her to remember just how abusive he was.

My little girl is 5 and she's always had some anger issues, but she recently started kindergarten and has been suspended too many times to count (almost every week). She's in her 4th kindergarten class and she's getting kicked out again. Her school has run out of teachers for her and so she's being sent to a different school.

She sees a counselor every week, we've taken her to doctors, given her classes. We've even tried things at home like punching bags and sensory bottles and it seems as though nothing will help. Her counselor has decided it's a case of post traumatic stress disorder (PTSD) from her father. She's only 5 and it's killing me watching her life fall apart at such a young age. Any suggestions?

Comment: I cannot offer much.  Keep trying, don't give up.  Sometimes it takes awhile for something to click, kind of like a delayed effect.  Once she is older learning forgiveness of herself and of others will be important.  She is probably too young to understand that now.

Comment: If she has already been to counselor, I think you should follow their suggestions and take advice from doctors for any medical situation. We may be able to identify any similar situation if you can tell us the specifics. That is, is there any particular pattern or situation where she gets angry ? Why was she suspended ? Did she harm other kids or any other reason

Comment: When you say she's seeing a counselor do you mean like a school guidance counselor or something?  If that is true and doesn't seem to be working, maybe an outside professional (psychiatrist maybe?) might be a better fit?  Just spit balling here, but if the current person doesn't seem to be helping, maybe someone else can be.

Comment: If you are a Christian, or just desperate enough, look into Inner Healing. A popular name in that area is Francis MacNutt. There may be churches in your area that have experience with this. With Inner Healing prayer I've received healing in days for things that would've taken years with traditional counseling. Your sister may have a different experience because she's much younger and her trauma is likely deeper, but I think it will help regardless.

Comment: What kind of doctor did you saw ? Specialist for children psychology ?

Comment: Your best bet is to find a professional therapist to keep working with her.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how possible this is for you but you might consider taking a year and homeschooling her.  Spend as much time as possible generating positive experiences and then try regular school again next fall.

This school year is mostly about reading/writing anyway and it would be a great bonding experience for you both.

Answer (score 1):

Try a child PSYCHIATRIST. This is what they do all day long, and they may give you some good advice without medication.

If your child is getting expelled, then it's the parents' job to seek a doctor.